# How to use shell magic to create a recursive etags using GNU etags?

Tags: c++, bash, gnu, etag, exuberant-ctags

The standard GNU `etags` does not support a recursive walk of directories as done by exuberant `ctags -R`.  If I only have access to the GNU etags, how can I use bash shell magic to get etags to produce a TAGS table for all the C++ files `*.cpp` and `*.h` files in the current directory and all directories below the current one recursively to create a TAGS table in the current directory which has the proper path name for `emacs` to resolve the TAGS table entries.

Comment: How is it that you "only have access to the GNU etags"?  Exuberant ctags is freely available for many platforms.  Can't you install it?

Comment: Employer does not want unauthorized software installed, would rather not fight that if I can work around using provided `etags`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/) is often a good source for answers to common problems or best practices. For your specific problem there is a solution for both Windows and Unixen:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RecursiveTags#toc2

Basically you run a command to find all `.cpp` and all `.h` files (change file selectors if you use different file endings, such as e.g., `.C`) and pipe the result into etags. Since Windows does not seem to have xargs, you need a more recent version of etags that can read from stdin (note the dash at the end of the line which symbolizes stdin). Of course, if you use a recent version of etags, you can use the dash parameter instead of xargs there, too.

**Windows**:

```
cd c:\source-root
dir /b /s *.cpp *.h *.hpp | etags --your_options -
```

**Unix**:

```
cd /path/to/source-root
find . -name "*.cpp" -print -or -name "*.h" -print | xargs etags --append
```

Comment: using `xargs` limits the number of files to the max number of command-line args, the `etags -` version is preferable for large projects.

Comment: `find -name '*.cpp' -or -name '*.h' | ...` should be enough. You can also use `fd '\.(cpp|h)$' -X etags`. Is there a particular reason for using `--append`? I mean, is it faster? Produces no duplicates? A good default (it's generally best to use it every time)?

Answer (score 5):

This command creates etags file with default name "TAGS" for .c, .cpp, .Cpp, .hpp, .Hpp .h files recursively

```
find . -regex ".*\.[cChH]\(pp\)?" -print | etags -
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers posted here pipe the `find` output to `xargs`. This breaks if there are spaces in filenames inside the directory tree.

A more general solution that works if there are spaces in filenames (for `.c` and `.h` files) could be:

```
find . -name "*.[cChH]" -exec etags --append {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use find. man find if you need to.

Comment: and man xargs too, I bet.  . . . . or just install exuberant and use its etags ...