# How to jump to a Scheme definition in EMACS

Tags: emacs, scheme, racket

EMACS has the <kbd>Meta</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> key binding for SLIME, which only works in a limited fashion for Common Lisp.

Is there a more general way to go to a function definition that works with Scheme? Perhaps something that searches through the sources like Cscope?

Answer (score 2):

For Racket use `racket-mode` written by Greg Hendershott.

https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode

The documentation on `racket-visit-definition` to which `M-.` is bound.

[Docs on racket-visit-documentation](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode/blob/ac78c01354175e81cc2d709982028da27f6afe8d/Reference.md#racket-visit-definition)

Comment: That has even more stringent limitations than the SLIME version. It even sometimes requires you to use `racket-run`, which is documented as being similar to restarting the Racket REPL and reloading everything. Avoiding doing that (to the limited extent that it's possible with Racket) is one of the reasons I use EMACS instead of DrRacket. And it can't find anything that's in a different namespace, so if I can't find it with C-f, I won't be able to find it with this either.

Comment: Note that due to macros a find-definition facility is harder to implement in Scheme and Common Lisp than it is in C. As an example consider: (struct foo (bar)) after expansion the identifiers foo? foo-bar set-foo-bar! are available. None of these are present in the source.

Comment: Due to modules an identifer  sort  might be defined in several modules at once. The mode `racket-mode` will due to the namespace restriction be able to find the `sort` that is actually used where you invoke `racket-visit-definition`.

Comment: If you want to use `M-.` as a way to discover existing functions, then I can recommend searching both docs.racket-lang.org  as well as  github.org. At githun add language:racket to restrict result to Racket functions.

Comment: C has macros, too, and they cause the same kinds of problems. But having something that parses what can be parsed in the source is better than having to drop to a shell and run `grep -rl`, which is how I would find these definitions right now.

Comment: If you are interested on working on such a tool, maybe this could be a starting point?  https://github.com/soegaard/little-helper  (note: It has been a while since I tried it last - so don't expect a smooth experience)

Comment: All these REPL-based search tools have the same problem: They can't find definitions that you sent to the REPL with C-x e because the Lisp/Scheme process never sees the source file. SLIME has this problem, and it would also be present in Racket.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Geiser](https://github.com/jaor/geiser). It's the equivalent of SLIME for Scheme. <kbd>M-.</kbd> is there as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the tags files yourself using `etags` (similar to `ctags` for vim). These should work in vanilla emacs (without slime):

`etags *.scm`

`etags` won't walk directories recursively. As far as solutions for this, this looked promising: [How to use shell magic to create a recursive etags using GNU etags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738219/how-to-use-shell-magic-to-create-a-recursive-etags-using-gnu-etags#10747634)

etag docs: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/etags.html